# Inheritance implement

Tags: java, inheritance

I learn Java from a book. I finished already inheritance episode and I don't understand an example program in User Interfaces episode:

```
public class AWTApp extends Frame {
...
public AWTApp(String caption)
    {
        super(caption);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(PANELS_NO, 1));
        for(int i=0;i<PANELS_NO;i++)
        {
            panels[i]=new Panel();
            add(panels[i]);
        }
        label_test(panels[0]);
        ...
    }
}
```

This is the constructor in the main class(AWTApp) which inherits Frame class.
In the other example the frame is a variable in the main class(AWTApp) and to add components you write frame.add(component) ((Frame nam - frame, Component name - component)). How can they write in this code just add() or just pack() if there is no frame object?

Comment: `AWTApp` is a `Frame`. When you call `add()` in the constructor, you're calling it on `this`, which is a reference to an object of type `AWTApp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public class AWTApp extends Frame`

This means that AWTApp `is a` Frame

So when you call

```
public AWTApp(String caption)
    {
        super(caption); // here you are calling super constructor the frame constructor and creating the frame

       this.setLayout(new GridLayout(PANELS_NO, 1)); // cause you are a frame you can call with this parents public protected (and package if they are in the same package)
       this.add(..); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try to understand it better tomorrow. It is just hard to understand. Do you know where can I find exercises for inheritance? I just always find very hard excercises that consists content I haven't learnt yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some explanation.

First, some code:

```
public class Parent{

    public void doThing(){
        System.out.println("I did a thing!");
    }

}

public class Child extends Parent{

    public void doAnotherThing(){
        System.out.println("I did another thing!");
    }

}

public class MainClass{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Parent p = new Parent();
        Child c = new Child();
        p.doThing();
        c.doThing(); // This is correct because c is a Parent!
        c.doAnotherThing(); // This is correct, because c is also a child.
     }

}
```

`Child` inherits all of `Parent`s methods, because `Child` is just an extension of `Parent`. In the context of your program, this means that AWTApp can call all of Frame's methods because it IS a frame and therefore can do anything that a frame can do, plus its own methods.